# Non-Archimedan Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, model-theory

I'm trying to think of an explicit example of a non-Archimedian group.

The definition of Archimiedean is s.t. if for all $x$ and $y$, there is some $m$ a Natural number s.t. $mx = \underbrace {x + x + ... + x}_{m \text { times}}> y$.

An example I thought was playing around with the files, but not understanding why that would do it. Also, how can we use the compactness theorem to prove that one does exist?

Comment: [Did you look at the example given in the Wikipedia article on Archimedean groups?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_group#Examples_of_non-Archimedean_groups)

Comment: I didn't quite understand it and usage of Compactness theorem also

Comment: Do you know about non-Archimedean ordered fields, hyperreal fields for example?

Comment: There are plenty of concrete examples. For a non-constructive example, use index set $I$ the natural numbers, and a non-principal  ultrafilter $D$ on $I$. Then the ultrapower $\mathbb{Z}^I/D$ is an example, and we can replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't know about the ordered  fields that well. Same goes with ultrafilters. I'm trying to think of a concrete example then see how the compactness theorem can help to show that one exists

Comment: What do you know about model theory? If you don't know the basic tools (compactness, ultrapowers), then it seems you would benefit a lot from working on the basic parts first, then coming back to this example.

Comment: Well done for using three different spellings of the same word in such a short space, and never the correct one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an explicit example of a non-Archimedean ordered field that should be accessible to almost anyone who has taken real analysis, or maybe even just freshman calculus.

Consider the field of rational functions, that is, functions $f(x)$ that can be written as:

$$f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$

Where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials.  Define addition as $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and multiplication as $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$.

It is easy to verify that this set forms a field.  The ordering is a bit more tricky to define, but we can manage it by defining $f<g$ if $g$ eventually exceeds $f$: $$f < g \iff \exists r \in \mathbb R \forall x > r: f(x) < g(x)$$

The only tricky part of the proof that $<$ makes the field an ordered field is proving that for all rational functions $f \ne g$, $f<g$ or $g < f$.  For a hint, prove the simpler statement $f < 0 \lor 0 < f$ by taking a maximal root of a polynomial and using Bolzano's theorem.

But it should be clear that this field is not Archimedean.  Taking the multiplicative identity $1(x) = 1$, it should be clear that for any fixed $n$, $n\cdot 1 < I$ where $I(x) = x$.

This is an example of a non-Archimedean ordered field $( X , + , \cdot , <)$.  So *a fortiori*, the set of rational functions, under addition and the order $<$ form a non-Archimedean group.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I have misunderstood your question badly, you don't really need compactness for this, or anything nearly as complicated.

${\bf Z}^2$ with lexicographic order fits the description nicely: no multiple of $(0,1)$ is larger than $(1,0)$.

Actually, any product of (nontrivial) ordered groups ordered lexicographically will exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Good answer.  But that is the example on the web page Zev cited, and Buddy said he didn't understand it.

Comment: @GEdgar: Frankly, I haven't checked the page. If he really doesn't understand this example, he can just ask in a comment, and in any event, this is the simplest example possible.

Comment: Also, I agree that compactness, ultrafilters, model theory, etc. should be avoided in replying to this guy.